# Are there any dangers of storing program configuration data in global variable?

Tags: python, linux, signals

I have a Python program which is designed to be a systemd daemon and re-reads its configuration files when the program receives the `SIGHUP` signal. Parsed content of those configuration files are kept in a global list. Whole structure of the program looks like this:

```
def read_confs(signalNumber, frame):
# Set the conf_files variable, print messages about
# received signal, etc and finally call the create_threads()

  create_threads(conf_files)


def create_threads(conf_files):

  global threads
  threads = []

  # Read the conf files and build the "threads" array.

  return threads


def main():

  global threads
  threads = create_threads(conf_files)

  while True:

    # Process the "threads" list, call other functions, and endlessly create
    # sub-processes based on "threads" list.


if __name__ == "__main__":

  signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, read_confs)
  main()
```

As seen above, I'm using global list type variable `threads`, which is populated once the program starts and each time the program receives the `SIGHUP`. It seems to work fine, but as I have read, the usage of global variables can be dangerous. Is it fine to use global variables like this? Is there a more elegant/robust way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Actually, it's populated twice since both `create_threads` and `main` set the global variable.  Why is `threads` not just local to `main`?

Comment: Is your program actually multithreaded (as the variable name suggests)?

Comment: @stark Isn't vars defined in functions local to functions by default? Based on my tests the content of the `threads`, which is endlessly processed in `main()`, does not change if I don't specify both in `main()` and `create_threads()` that it is a global var. `threads` is not local to `main()` because I need to update it with `create_threads()` which is called by `read_confs()`(when the program receives the `SIGHUP` signal). However, maybe there is a much more elegant way to do this without global variables. @Davis Herring Yes, I'm using `ThreadPoolExecutor` in this endless loop in `main()`.